# Elasticsearch Allow Access from localhost, and two other ips

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch server setup at

```
http://hostname:9200.
```

The server is bound to the local host in elasticsearch.yml as specified in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-on-an-ubuntu-vps. This works to only allow the localhost to connect to the server. I would need to allow two other servers (worker nodes) to connect to the server to put data there. How can I bind additional ips so that the elasticsearch server can be accessed from localhost and the two other ips?

Comment: did you have any success with this yet ?